# How to check if my date range is totally covered by CONSECUTIVE rows?

Tags: c#

I need to check if a date range is totally covered by this date range table sorted in ascending order of dFrom, both are Date type:

```
dFrom  dTo
-----  -----
10/01  10/03
10/05  10/08
10/08  10/09
10/09  10/12
10/13  10/18
10/15  10/17
10/19  10/24
```

`range A: 10/01-10/14` is NOT totally covered because **10/04** is missing from table.

`range B: 10/10-10/20` is totally covered.

What I can think of is for a given date range like A and B, to check if each day is covered in the table:

```
var dRangeFrom = rangeFrom.Date; // use "var" as C# has no date type
var dRangeTo = rangeTo.Date;
int DaysCovered = 0;
int HowManyDays = (dRangeTo - dRangeFrom).TotalDays()+1;
int StartFromRow = 0;
while (dRangeFrom <= dRangeTo)
{
  for (int i=StartFromRow; i<table.rows.count; i++)
  {
    if (table.rows[i]["dFrom"] > dRangeFrom)  // optimization 1: no need to continue.
      break;
    if (dRangeFrom >= table.rows[i]["dFrom"] && dRangeFrom <= table.rows[i]["dTo"])
    {
      DaysCovered++;
      StartFromRow = i;   // optimization 2: next day comparison simply starts from here 
      break;
    }
  }
  dRangeFrom.AddDays(1);
} 
if (DaysCovered == HowManyDays)
  Console.Write("Totally covered");
else
  Console.Write("NOT");
```

Comment: "C# has no date type", System.DateTime?

Comment: `var` is just an implicit type that gets resolved by the compiler - it's not an actual type itself. The actual type is `DateTime`. If you hover over `var`, it will show you the type in a tooltip in most IDEs.

Comment: `table`, `dFrom` and `dTo` are not defined in the code sample. Please post a minimal sample that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it would be to write a helper method that gets all the days in a range:

```
public static List<DateTime> GetDaysCovered(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    var result = new List<DateTime>();

    for (var i = 0; i < (to.Date - from.Date).TotalDays; i++)
    {
        result.Add(from.Date.AddDays(i));
    }

    return result;
}
```

And then we can join all the ranges from the table together and see if they match the days  in the range we're trying to cover:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    tableDates.AddRange(GetDaysCovered(
        row.Field<DateTime>("dFrom").Date, 
        row.Field<DateTime>("dTo").Date));
}

var rangeDates = GetDaysCovered(dRangeFrom, dRangeTo);

var missingDates = rangeDates
    .Where(rangeDate => !tableDates.Contains(rangeDate))
    .ToList();

if (missingDates.Any())
{
    Console.Write("These dates are not covered: ");
    Console.Write(string.Join(",", 
        missingDates.Select(date => date.ToShortDateString())));
}
else
{
    Console.Write("Totally covered");
}
```

Comment: Terrific sample. I surely will learn from. With optimization added to my original code, I believe performance and readability will improve. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution is to check for each date in the range whether it is covered by any row.

```
var totallyCovered = true;

for (var date = rangeFrom.Date; date <= rangeTo.Date; date = date.AddDays(1)) 
{
    var covered = dates.Any(x => date >= x.dFrom && date <= x.dTo);

    if (!covered)
    {
        totallyCovered = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (totallyCovered)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Totally covered.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No.");
}
```

That's kinda long and ugly, but thankfully you can fit that into a single LINQ query:

```
var dateRange = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + rangeTo.Subtract(rangeFrom).Days)
          .Select(offset => rangeFrom.Date.AddDays(offset));
var totallyCovered = dateRange.All(d => dates.Any(x => d >= x.dFrom && d <= x.dTo));
```

---

Note: This has time complexity of `O(|range| * |rows|)`, which might be too much. To fix that you'd have to employ a more sophisticated data structure that would allow you to query ranges in logarithmic time, but since your original sample also contained nested loops, I'll assume it's unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. Since LinQ is actually `foreach` behind the scene, with 2 optimization added in my original code, performance is ok. Also I believe it's easier for anyone reading my code understands the algorithm.

Comment: @Jeb50 I agree, the performance would be an issue only if you had hundreds of thousands of rows.